# what is the difference between two ways of assigning methods to a delegate object

Tags: c#

Consider this fragment:

```
public delegate void PrintSomeText(string);
```

And somewhere legal we have the following method:

```
public void ShowText(string s) { Console.WriteLine(s); }
```

What is(are) the difference(s) between the two ways of assigning `ShowText` method to the `printObj` below?

```
static void Main()
{
    PrintSomeText printObj;
    /* ... */
    printObj = new PrintSomeText(ShowText); // The first way
}
```

vs. :

```
static void Main()
{
    PrintSomeText printObj;
    /* ... */
    printObj = ShowText; // The second way
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference. Starting with .NET 2.0 / VS2005, the C# compiler added an improvement that automatically inferred the type of delegate based on the left side of the assignment, and implicitly added the `new PrintSomeText` call to the compiled code. Post-compilation, they are identical.

Answer (score 1):

Effectively, they are no different at all. The second method, introduced in C# 2.0, is just more concise.

For more information, check out [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173176.aspx)